# Why the second statement does not work?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Can you help me in debugging this code snippet?
It should evaluate the `emacs-major-version` and sets the color theme accordingly. I've tested the first statement, the second does not return any error but the theme does not be applied. Any clue?

```
(if (<= emacs-major-version 23)
    ((require 'color-theme)
     (eval-after-load "color-theme"
        '(progn
           (color-theme-initialize)
           (color-theme-classic))))
    (progn
    (setq custom-enabled-themes (quote (tango-dark)))
    (setq custom-safe-themes (quote
         ("16248150e4336572ff4aa21321015d37c3744a9eb243fbd1e934b594ff9cf394"
          "9370aeac615012366188359cb05011aea721c73e1cb194798bc18576025cabeb"
          default))))
)
```

Comment: In `elisp`, you cannot call more than one function as part of the `then` statement, unless it is wrapped in something like `progn` or another type of wrapper.  In your `then` statement, you are calling first `(require 'color-theme)` and then you are calling a second function -- i.e., `(eval-after-load "color-theme" '(progn (color-theme-initialize) (color-theme-classic)))`  Merely wrapping your `then` statement in parentheses (as you have done) is insufficient.  In `elisp`, an `else` statement does not generally need `progn` (unless there is some *special reason* why it would be needed).

Comment: `(if (<= emacs-major-version 23) (progn (require 'color-theme) (eval-after-load "color-theme" '(progn (color-theme-initialize) (color-theme-classic)))) (setq custom-enabled-themes (quote (tango-dark))) (setq custom-safe-themes (quote ("16248150e4336572ff4aa21321015d37c3744a9eb243fbd1e934b594ff9cf394" "9370aeac615012366188359cb05011aea721c73e1cb194798bc18576025cabeb" default))))`  Because I can't test the functionality of your function (given my current Emacs installation), I'm not yet comfortable posting it as an answer (until we know it works for you).

Comment: What do you mean by "first condition"? There is only one condition.

Comment: Ops! I meant "statement", my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditional works after dealing with the `progn` issue that lawlist brought up, but you forgot to load the theme.  Add `(load-theme 'tango-dark t)` at the end of the second `progn` as such:

```
(if (<= emacs-major-version 23)
    (progn
      (require 'color-theme)
      (eval-after-load "color-theme"
        '(progn
           (color-theme-initialize)
           (color-theme-classic))))
  (progn
    (setq custom-enabled-themes (quote (tango-dark)))
    (setq custom-safe-themes (quote
                              ("16248150e4336572ff4aa21321015d37c3744a9eb243fbd1e934b594ff9cf394"
                               "9370aeac615012366188359cb05011aea721c73e1cb194798bc18576025cabeb"
                               default)))
    (load-theme 'tango-dark t)))    ; add me here
```

*Edited re: Phils's comment:* sorry, I missed the `require` in the initial code.  The first clause is now wrapped in a `progn` as needed.

Comment: Whoops, missed that.  Now edited to wrap the `require` and the `eval-after-load` in a `progn`.  I'm on v. 24, so I know the second clause works.

Comment: You still have two parens before the `require`, which I believe is a syntax error.

Comment: Sloppy way to run a railroad!  You're correct: it's fixed now.

Comment: I do not believe the **third** `(progn` is needed -- i.e., the last `(progn` just before `(setq custom-enabled-themes . . .`.  The `else` portion (of an `if/then/else` statement) will run more than one function without it.

Comment: Holy moly, you're right!  I never knew that.  That being said, the extra `progn` is harmless and it might be a good idea to leave it in to preserve the symmetry for reading purposes (ie, as a visual reminder that everything that follows is the body of the *else* clause).

Comment: It is **never** a good idea to throw in extra stuff that does *absolutely nothing* to the overall functionality.  The proper place for extra stuff that does *absolutely nothing* is in a comment -- e.g., `;; this is my comment`  It is also customary to do what you want to achieve with indentations -- i.e., the `then` portion of the `if/then/else` statement is indented farther than the `else` portion.

Comment: Fair enough, but that strikes me as a little stringent.  So, for example, the two calls to `setq` in the *else* clause could be combined into one, but it might be harder to follow.  I'm guessing the original poster is just starting with lisp, so keeping it easy to follow seems like the way to go here.

Comment: Thanks to everybody but still there's something I can't understand: why have I to add `(load-theme 'tango-dark t)`? I've looked at another dotemacs where `custom-enabled-themes` and `custom-safe-themes` are inserted within the `custom-set-variables` block, and there the `load-theme...` is missing.